# List Item with Toggle subview and selection gesture

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List and items containing a `Toggle` view. I would like to handle selection and toggle state separately. the toggle should be disabled when list item is not selected.
The problem is:

1. first tap - selects the list item. (`selected = true`)
2. tap on toggle - set `selection = false`

On UIKit, Button/Switch/etc... catch the 'tap' and do not pass through to TableView selection state.

```
struct ListView: View {
    @State var selected = Set<Int>()
    let items = (1...10).map { ItemDataModel(id: $0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            ListItemView(dataModel: item)
                .onTapGesture { if !(selected.remove(item.id) != .none) { selected.insert(item.id) }}
        }
    }
}

struct ListItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: ItemDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(dataModel.title)
            Spacer()
            Toggle(
                isOn:Binding<Bool>(get: {dataModel.isOn}, set: {dataModel.isOn = $0}),
                label: { Text("toggle") })
        }
    }
}

class ItemDataModel: Hashable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        title = "item \(id)"
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ItemDataModel, rhs: ItemDataModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

[Please try to ignore syntax errors (if exsist) and focus on the gesture issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `[ItemDataModel]` array should be moved outside the body, so it's not recreated every time:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @State var selected = Set<Int>()
    let items = (1...10).map(ItemDataModel.init) // move outside the `body`

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(describing: selected))
            List(items) { item in
                ListItemView(dataModel: item)
                    .onTapGesture { if !(selected.remove(item.id) != .none) { selected.insert(item.id) }}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, make sure that the `Toggle` in your `ListItemView` doesn't take all the space (that's the default behaviour) and attach `onTapGesture` to override the parent's gesture:

```
struct ListItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: ItemDataModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(dataModel.title)
            // Text("toggle") // if necessary add Toggle's label as `Text`
            Spacer()
            Toggle("", isOn: $dataModel.isOn) // use another initialiser
                .fixedSize() // limit Toggle's width
                .background(Color.red) // debug-only, to see the real frame
                .onTapGesture {} // override tap gestures
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle()) // make empty space *clickable*
    }
}
```

Comment: If I explicitly implement `onTapGesture` for the `Toggle`, when I tap on it, the toggle 'onTap' will be called and the superview's 'onTap' will not?

Comment: I have the same issue with a `Picker`. replace `Toggle` with `Picker` (`SegmentedPickerStyle`) and now adding `onTap` disables the cell selection (as I want), but, also disables the `picker` action.
I tried setting `onTap` to each of the segments individually, but that does not work either.

Comment: @gutte Please create a new post with your new question. I'll try to help you there (once you create it, you can ping a link here).

Comment: here is my second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516795/list-item-with-picker-segmented-control-subview-and-selection-gesture
@pawello2222