# List Item with Picker (segmented control) subview and selection gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List and items containing a Picker view (segmented control stye). I would like to handle selection and picker state separately. the picker should be disabled when list item is not selected.

The problem is:

- first tap - selects the list item. (selected = true)
- tap on picker - set selection = false

On UIKit, Button/SegmentControl/etc... catch the 'tap' and do not pass through to TableView selection state.

```
struct ListView: View {
    @State var selected = Set<Int>()
    let items = (1...10).map { ItemDataModel(id: $0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            ListItemView(dataModel: item)
                .onTapGesture { if !(selected.remove(item.id) != .none) { selected.insert(item.id) }}
        }
    }
}

struct ListItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: ItemDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        let pickerBinding = Binding<Int>(
            get: { dataModel.state?.rawValue ?? -1 },
            set: { dataModel.state = DataState(rawValue: $0) }
        )
        HStack {
            Text(dataModel.title)
            Spacer()
            Picker("sdf", selection: pickerBinding) {
                Text("State 1").tag(0)
                Text("State 2").tag(1)
                Text("State 3").tag(2)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}


enum DataState: Int {
    case state1, state2, state3
}

class ItemDataModel: Hashable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    @Published var state: DataState? = .state1
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        title = "item \(id)"
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ItemDataModel, rhs: ItemDataModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

[Please try to ignore syntax errors (if exsist) and focus on the gesture issue]

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to apply modifiers only when the `Picker` is not selected:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @State var selected = Set<Int>()
    let items = (1 ... 10).map { ItemDataModel(id: $0) }

    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            if selected.contains(item.id) {
                ListItemView(dataModel: item)
            } else {
                ListItemView(dataModel: item)
                    .disabled(true)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if !(selected.remove(item.id) != .none) {
                            selected.insert(item.id)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: scenario: when the item is 'selected' and I wish to change the pick on the picker.
outcome: item gets unselected instead of changing the status enum by Picker.
I don't understand how your suggestion solves that

Comment: @gutte I'm not sure I understand what you need then. Can you describe your issue more clearly - possibly add all the scenarios to the question?